# print lines in a range pattern from a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I Have file log.txt :

```
======================
Tue Jun 25 00:02:00 WIT 2013
======================


pool
    INFO     name               work
    INFO     threads.total      30
    INFO     threads.active     7
    INFO     threads.waiting    23
    INFO     jobs.queue.latency 0
    INFO     jobs.run.latency   139
    INFO     jobs.queue.tps     3
    INFO     jobs.start.tps     3
    INFO     jobs.finish.tps    3
    NORMAL   jobs.count         0
pool
    INFO     name               recv
    INFO     threads.total      40
    INFO     threads.active     27
    INFO     threads.waiting    13
    INFO     jobs.queue.latency 0
    INFO     jobs.run.latency   0
    INFO     jobs.queue.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.start.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.finish.tps    0
    NORMAL   jobs.count         0
pool
    INFO     name               send
    INFO     threads.total      10
    INFO     threads.active     0
    INFO     threads.waiting    10
    INFO     jobs.queue.latency 0
    INFO     jobs.run.latency   1
    INFO     jobs.queue.tps     5
    INFO     jobs.start.tps     5
    INFO     jobs.finish.tps    5
    NORMAL   jobs.count         0


======================
Tue Jun 25 00:03:00 WIT 2013
======================

pool
    INFO     name               work
    INFO     threads.total      30
    INFO     threads.active     15
    INFO     threads.waiting    15
    INFO     jobs.queue.latency 0
    INFO     jobs.run.latency   13
    INFO     jobs.queue.tps     1
    INFO     jobs.start.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.finish.tps    0
    NORMAL   jobs.count         46
    INFO     jobs.1.type        request

pool
    INFO     name               recv
    INFO     threads.total      40
    INFO     threads.active     27
    INFO     threads.waiting    13
    INFO     jobs.queue.latency 0
    INFO     jobs.run.latency   0
    INFO     jobs.queue.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.start.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.finish.tps    0
    NORMAL   jobs.count         0
pool
    INFO     name               send
    INFO     threads.total      10
    INFO     threads.active     0
    INFO     threads.waiting    10
    INFO     jobs.queue.latency 0
    INFO     jobs.run.latency   0
    INFO     jobs.queue.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.start.tps     0
    INFO     jobs.finish.tps    0
    NORMAL   jobs.count         0
```

I want result like this :

---

```
======================
Tue Jun 25 00:03:00 WIT 2013
======================
    INFO     name               work
    NORMAL   jobs.count         46
    INFO     jobs.1.type        request
```

---

I already use:

```
cat log.txt |grep -B14 -A1 -i 'jobs.count         [1-9]\{2,\}' |
egrep -i "jobs.1.type|=|WIT|jobs.count         [1-9]"
```

The problem if name not "work" but "send" or "recv", so "grep -B14" will not get the date.
Any other solution? On the other hand, I want grep if "jobs.count" not "0" than get date ="Tue Jun 25 00:03:00 WIT 2013" , get name ="INFO     name               work" and get jobs type "INFO     jobs.1.type        request":

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  I've tried to format your question more clearly, but I'm not at all sure it is correct yet.  I'm also very unclear on what you are asking.  To display code and log files etc as constant width font, select the code and then use the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  This indents the code uniformly by 4 spaces, producing the constant width layout.  The lines of dashes and equals produce formatting effects when in column 1.

Comment: Yes its my question. Thank you for editing

Comment: Your regex will fail to match when the count is an even multiple of 10.  You probably want `[1-9][0-9]*` instead, or simply `[0-9]+` if zero is also a valid result.

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
/WIT|INFO +name|jobs.1.type|jobs.count +[1-9]/{
if ($0 ~ /WIT/)
    {cheader=$0}
if ($0 ~ /INFO +name/)
    {cname=$0}
if ($0 ~ /jobs.count +[1-9]/)
    {ccount=$0}
if ($0 ~ /jobs.1.type/)
    {
    i++
    header[i]=cheader
    name[i]=cname
    count[i]=ccount
    type[i]=$0
    }
}
END {
    line="======================"
    for (a=1 ;a<=i ;a++)
    {
    if (count[a] != "")
        {
        print line
        print header[a]
        print line
        print name[a]
        print count[a]
        print type[a]
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output example:

```
$awk -f c.awk file
======================
Tue Jun 25 00:03:00 WIT 2013
======================
    INFO     name               work
    NORMAL   jobs.count         46
    INFO     jobs.1.type        request
```

Comment: Will this really work if you have more than one `pool` under `header` with a `jobs.count > 0`? Since you only increase `i` with new headers.

Comment: @Qben yes, you are right, thanks. The source is "awkward", I put the counter to `jobs.1.type`. But this might be not enough, and a counter for every field is maybe needed. Kind of `array of counters`.

Comment: Hi @Qben, Thanks work perfect I just edit "if ($0 ~ /jobs.count +[1-9]/)" become "if ($0 ~ /jobs.count +[1-9][0-9][0-9]/)" so only print 3 digit jobscount ( jobs.count > 100)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/WIT/ {date=$0} /name/ {printf "\n%s\n%s\n", date, $0} /count|type/' file | 
awk -v RS="" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i~/count/ && $(i+1)>0) {print; break}}'
```

```
Tue Jun 25 00:03:00 WIT 2013
    INFO     name               work
    NORMAL   jobs.count         46
    INFO     jobs.1.type        request
```

The first awk prints paragraphs containing the date and the fields you want.
The second awk read paragraphs and only prints those with count > 0.

Comment: `\n....|..RS=""..` very nice and really _graceful_!

Comment: oops, logic error. I need to check that the field after "count" is not zero. I was checking the *last* field (i.e. "request") was > 0